# Logging REST traffic in Java EE (or HTTP in general)

Tags: java, rest, http, jakarta-ee, logging

I had a look around for a Java solution to logging REST or HTTP calls in general in a Java EE environment to a database for later analysis but I haven't been successful so far.

My requirements are logging the request and response of course, including some meta data like the ip of the requesting side (client/server), the currently authenticated user and the status code. This should happen in way that you could search for this meta data in a efficient way so that there is not much stress on the database and you could build a log browser on top of it which can present you with results without being unresponsive even if there were several million log entries.

A nice to have would be that the log viewer is already there and does not have to be built.

Do I have to implement this myself or is there any solution that I could throw in?

Comment: You obviously didn't have a very good look. log4j has a JDBCAppender and logback has a DBAppender. Both let you log events to the database.

Comment: Most Containers have the ability to log request information. Which one are you using?

Comment: I should probably edit my entry as I see that it is indeed misleading. The logging itself is a problem that can be easily tackled, indeed, it's more about the thing that someone already put effort in thinking about data structures as we had quite some discussion about how to build a good model so that you could use filters on the results without too much stress on the database.